# Angular read-only attribute

Tags: html, angular, typescript, input, readonly

```
 <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="data.orderSource">
                            <option value="">Select</option>
                            <option *ngFor="let source of orderSources" [value]="source.id">{{source.name}}</option>
                          </select>
```

Here if user selects `source.id == 21`, I want to disable below input ?

```
    <td style="width: 150px;">
                              <input type="number" step="any"[readonly]="data.orderSource ==21"
                                [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': item.qty > item.stockCount || (item.unitPrice < item.sellingPrice && roleId !== 1)}"
                                (input)="calculatedAmount($event, item)" class="form-control"
                                [(ngModel)]="item.unitPrice" [ngModelOptions]="{ standalone: true }"
                                 [min]="item.sellingPrice">
                              <span *ngIf="item.unitPrice < item.sellingPrice && roleId !== 1" class="text-danger">
                                Unit price cannot be below the selling price.
                              </span>
                            </td>
```

here is the array of orderSource?

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Facebook Message",
        "inventoryAccount": {
            "id": 200,
            "name": "Dropex",
            "image": "1618589868066_Dropex.png",
            "email": "hasitha4520@gmail.com",
            "phone": "0776762331",
            "address": "Colombo",
            "prefix": "dr",
            "pickEnabled": true,
            "commissionAccount": null
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Call Orders",
        "inventoryAccount": {
            "id": 200,
            "name": "Dropex",
            "image": "1618589868066_Dropex.png",
            "email": "hasitha4520@gmail.com",
            "phone": "0776762331",
            "address": "Colombo",
            "prefix": "dr",
            "pickEnabled": true,
            "commissionAccount": null
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Website",
        "inventoryAccount": {
            "id": 200,
            "name": "Dropex",
            "image": "1618589868066_Dropex.png",
            "email": "hasitha4520@gmail.com",
            "phone": "0776762331",
            "address": "Colombo",
            "prefix": "dr",
            "pickEnabled": true,
            "commissionAccount": null
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 11,
        "name": "Facebook Signup",
        "inventoryAccount": {
            "id": 200,
            "name": "Dropex",
            "image": "1618589868066_Dropex.png",
            "email": "hasitha4520@gmail.com",
            "phone": "0776762331",
            "address": "Colombo",
            "prefix": "dr",
            "pickEnabled": true,
            "commissionAccount": null
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 12,
        "name": "Whatsapp ",
        "inventoryAccount": {
            "id": 200,
            "name": "Dropex",
            "image": "1618589868066_Dropex.png",
            "email": "hasitha4520@gmail.com",
            "phone": "0776762331",
            "address": "Colombo",
            "prefix": "dr",
            "pickEnabled": true,
            "commissionAccount": null
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 13,
        "name": "Viber",
        "inventoryAccount": {
            "id": 200,
            "name": "Dropex",
            "image": "1618589868066_Dropex.png",
            "email": "hasitha4520@gmail.com",
            "phone": "0776762331",
            "address": "Colombo",
            "prefix": "dr",
            "pickEnabled": true,
            "commissionAccount": null
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 14,
        "name": "Imo",
        "inventoryAccount": {
            "id": 200,
            "name": "Dropex",
            "image": "1618589868066_Dropex.png",
            "email": "hasitha4520@gmail.com",
            "phone": "0776762331",
            "address": "Colombo",
            "prefix": "dr",
            "pickEnabled": true,
            "commissionAccount": null
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 15,
        "name": "Instagram",
        "inventoryAccount": {
            "id": 200,
            "name": "Dropex",
            "image": "1618589868066_Dropex.png",
            "email": "hasitha4520@gmail.com",
            "phone": "0776762331",
            "address": "Colombo",
            "prefix": "dr",
            "pickEnabled": true,
            "commissionAccount": null
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 16,
        "name": "Dropshipping",
        "inventoryAccount": {
            "id": 200,
            "name": "Dropex",
            "image": "1618589868066_Dropex.png",
            "email": "hasitha4520@gmail.com",
            "phone": "0776762331",
            "address": "Colombo",
            "prefix": "dr",
            "pickEnabled": true,
            "commissionAccount": null
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 17,
        "name": "Facebook Comment",
        "inventoryAccount": {
            "id": 200,
            "name": "Dropex",
            "image": "1618589868066_Dropex.png",
            "email": "hasitha4520@gmail.com",
            "phone": "0776762331",
            "address": "Colombo",
            "prefix": "dr",
            "pickEnabled": true,
            "commissionAccount": null
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 18,
        "name": "Daraz",
        "inventoryAccount": {
            "id": 200,
            "name": "Dropex",
            "image": "1618589868066_Dropex.png",
            "email": "hasitha4520@gmail.com",
            "phone": "0776762331",
            "address": "Colombo",
            "prefix": "dr",
            "pickEnabled": true,
            "commissionAccount": null
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 19,
        "name": "Daraz-Re Order Confirmation",
        "inventoryAccount": {
            "id": 200,
            "name": "Dropex",
            "image": "1618589868066_Dropex.png",
            "email": "hasitha4520@gmail.com",
            "phone": "0776762331",
            "address": "Colombo",
            "prefix": "dr",
            "pickEnabled": true,
            "commissionAccount": null
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 20,
        "name": "Wholesale",
        "inventoryAccount": {
            "id": 200,
            "name": "Dropex",
            "image": "1618589868066_Dropex.png",
            "email": "hasitha4520@gmail.com",
            "phone": "0776762331",
            "address": "Colombo",
            "prefix": "dr",
            "pickEnabled": true,
            "commissionAccount": null
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 21,
        "name": "Exchange",
        "inventoryAccount": {
            "id": 200,
            "name": "Dropex",
            "image": "1618589868066_Dropex.png",
            "email": "hasitha4520@gmail.com",
            "phone": "0776762331",
            "address": "Colombo",
            "prefix": "dr",
            "pickEnabled": true,
            "commissionAccount": null
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 38,
        "name": "Showroom Visit",
        "inventoryAccount": {
            "id": 200,
            "name": "Dropex",
            "image": "1618589868066_Dropex.png",
            "email": "hasitha4520@gmail.com",
            "phone": "0776762331",
            "address": "Colombo",
            "prefix": "dr",
            "pickEnabled": true,
            "commissionAccount": null
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 39,
        "name": "Facebook Leads",
        "inventoryAccount": {
            "id": 200,
            "name": "Dropex",
            "image": "1618589868066_Dropex.png",
            "email": "hasitha4520@gmail.com",
            "phone": "0776762331",
            "address": "Colombo",
            "prefix": "dr",
            "pickEnabled": true,
            "commissionAccount": null
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 42,
        "name": "TAC",
        "inventoryAccount": {
            "id": 200,
            "name": "Dropex",
            "image": "1618589868066_Dropex.png",
            "email": "hasitha4520@gmail.com",
            "phone": "0776762331",
            "address": "Colombo",
            "prefix": "dr",
            "pickEnabled": true,
            "commissionAccount": null
        }
    }
]
```

I want to make "readonly" the input field if "order Source" is "Exchange"? can you help me to doi t

Comment: Your code should work fine. What issue you are facing ? Can you please create a minimal reproducible demo and share the link of Angular playground.